# Chechboxes in Tkinter

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, boolean

I'm new to GUIs, and I'm writing some code segments for school. This is an issue I've been having in multiple assignments and I can't seem to wrap my head around it. When I implement checkboxes, the value returned is always positive regardless of whether or not I check to box. For example, this is a code I've been writing that is supposed to create a menu for the user to select from, and them display the correct total:

```
from tkinter import * 
def main(): 
    class Application(Frame):
        #GUI application that creates a menu to be chosen from and selections    to be made.
        def __init__(self, master):
            #Initialize Frame. 
            Frame.__init__(self, master)
            self.grid()
            self.createWidgets()

        def addPrices(self):
            #store price float
            price = 0.00

        #add all contents of the list selected
        #use if statement to determine which prices need to be added
            if self.isPizza:
                price += 3.00
            if self.isFries:
                price += 0.50
            if self.isCoke:
                price += 0.25
            if self.isChurro:
                price += 1.50 

        #display totals
        #Use label to print total
            Label(self,text = "Your total is: ").grid(row = 9, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
            Label(self,text = price).grid(row = 10, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)   


        def createWidgets(self):
            #create instruction label 
            Label(self,text = "Please Select your Items:").grid(row = 0, column = 4, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

            #create labels for checkboxes / menu
            Label(self,text = "Pizza.... $3.00").grid(row = 1, column = 5, sticky = W)
            Label(self,text = "Fries... $0.50").grid(row = 2, column = 5,  sticky = W)
            Label(self,text = "Coke... $0.25").grid(row = 3, column = 5,  sticky = W)
            Label(self,text = "Churro... $1.50").grid(row = 4, column = 5, sticky = W)

            #create input via checkboxes 
            #Create a plain of checkboxes to select items 
            self.isPizza = BooleanVar()
            Checkbutton(self,text = "Pizza",variable = self.isPizza).grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = W)
            self.isFries = BooleanVar()
            Checkbutton(self, text = "Fries",variable = self.isFries).grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W)
            self.isCoke = BooleanVar()
            Checkbutton(self, text = "Coke",variable = self.isCoke).grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = W)
            self.isChurro = BooleanVar()
            Checkbutton(self, text = "Churro",variable = self.isChurro).grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = W)

            #Create submit button 
            Button(self,text = "Click to submit order",command = self.addPrices).grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = W)



    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("800x400") 
    root.title(" Order Up!")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

The program always returns 5.25 as the total, which is just the amount of all items added together. Am I missing a segments that will change my Boolean variables depending on user input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter Checkbutton doesn't change my variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469254/tkinter-checkbutton-doesnt-change-my-variable)

Comment: @NikitaKniazev The checkbuttons are changing the Var.  The OP is not testing the Var properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the boolean value of the each Var's value, not of the Var itself.
Change `if self.isPizza:` to `if self.isPizza.get():`, etc, and your program works.

PS Wrapping your entire program in `def main:` and calling `main()`, as you did, is useless and wastes an indentation level and makes the program harder to read.  If you want to make a file useful for import, as well as direct running, define your top-level classes and functions as module level and only put code that does things that should not happen on import inside `main`, and then guard the execution of main.  In this case:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:
...
def main():
    root = Tk()
    ...
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can now import this file into a test file and test the Application class without root.mainloop() taking control.